# Which adjective makes sense in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

> Students might not only have ------- time to finish it but also they
>   have no time to  think it deeply.

**Enough** or **scarce**?

Answer (score 1):

This is a sentence in 2 halves the first

> Students might not only have **enough** time to finish

then the second

> but also they have no time to think it deeply

does the second half make sense with enough used?

> Students might not only have **scarce** time to finish

does the second half make sense now?

> ***scarce*** adjective UK ​
>
> not easy to find or
>   get:
>
> Food and clean water were becoming scarce.
>
> scarce resources

[cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scarce)